# Are core extensions with old dates or version 3.0.0 obsolete?

Tags: extensions, security

I'm working on a current-version site that was original built with J!1.5.x (or even 1.0.x). There are many extensions with dates in the 2004-2007 range. I'm wondering if they're obsolete and can be removed for space savings and security.

For example:

[image]

My approach would be to disable them first, and later delete them if no harm seems to have come. I'd appreciate a more definitive answer regarding stagnant dates and version numbers, though.

If I'm mistaken here, how would I identify extensions that were included in the 1.x.x package, but are no longer used? Is there any reason to assume that old extensions were removed by jUpdate or Joomla Update processes?

Also, my custom extensions get date updates with version updates. Why would the J! team not do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not obsolete at all ;)

All core extensions gets updated when needed. The date you're seeing is when they were first created, not updated.

So only delete/unpublish them if you don't require them on your site.

#### Update:

The date you're seeing on that page **should** show the creation date:

```
echo @$item->creationDate != '' ? $item->creationDate : '&#160;';
```

This will pull the creation date defined in the extension's XML file

If 3rd party developers decide to change the creation date for every update, that's their choice.

Comment: Any core extensions that ONLY belonged to older versions of Joomla will get automatically removed in the update. However I don't think any extensions have been removed that I know of